# Cypress error. cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element.

The element typed into was:

> ...

A typeable element matches one of the following selectors:
a[href]
area[href]
input
select
textarea
button
iframe
[tabindex]
[contenteditable]

I was trying to locate a field to enter date and it shows an error like this. But i have automated the field like same before without any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find an `<input>` within the `<div>`.

Not sure exactly what selectors you used, but this would be an example:

```js
cy.get('div.mat-form-field-infix')
  .find('input')
  .type('21-10-2022')
```

Comment: It worked but the filed get cleared after typing, Thank you and let me check the issue.